# Get First Record on Page in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'm looking for a way to get the first record on each page to be used on the page header or the table (Tablix) header.

For instance I'm looking to have something like "first(Fields!EmpName.Value, Global!PageNumber)" where each time the page changes the displayed name for the page changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the ReportItems collection. This gives you access to rendered output.

First find the name of the textbox that contains the data you want to show from you tablix (e.g. EmpName). note: this *may* not be the same as the field name, its the textbox name property you need. By defalut it will be the same as the field name, just check.

Then in your page header, add a textbox and set the expression to

```
=FIRST(ReportItems!textboxname.Value)
```